# AngularJS $http - slow

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, performance

Im using AngularJS on front-end and PHP on back-end that is hosted in Google App Engine. Now when i try to fetch JSONP data directly from server it goes fast, when i use a Google service the time increases with almost 1s. Very short: Im getting my data very slow, it takes 1.3-1.8s to render data on screen.

This is my Client-code-Controller:

```
angular
    .module('RDash')
    .controller('tables-ctrl5', ['$scope','$http', function($scope,$http) {
        $http({
            method: 'jsonp',
            url: 'https://gtmdocx.appspot.com/test5?callback=JSON_CALLBACK',
            headers: {"Content-Type":"application/json"}
        }).then(function ListCtrlresponses(response) {

            $scope.GTMWorkspacesTags = response.data.tag;
            console.log(response.data.tag);
            $scope.GTMWorkspacesTagsLength = response.data.tag.length;

        }, function Error(response) {
            $scope.users = response.statusText;
        });
    }])
```

im using ng-repeat:

```
   <div class="col-lg-6">
    <rd-widget>
      <rd-widget-header icon="fa-tasks" title="Google Tag Manager - URL: http://gtmdocx.appspot.com/test3 (LISTE AV TAGS I WORKSPACE) = Hent ut PATH fra LISTE av Workspace (EX: accounts/1746756959/containers/7454209/workspaces/8)">
      </rd-widget-header>
      <rd-widget-body classes="medium no-padding">
        <div class="table-responsive">
          <table class="table table-striped" ng-controller="tables-ctrl5">
            <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>AccountID</th>
              <th>ContainerID</th>
              <th>TagName</th>
              <th>Path</th>
              <th>test</th>


            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="workspace in GTMWorkspacesTags">
              <td>{{ workspace.accountId }}</td>
              <td>{{ workspace.containerId }}</td>
              <td>{{ workspace.name }}</td>
              <td>{{ workspace.path }}</td>
              <td>{{GTMWorkspacesTagstest}}</td>

            </tr>

            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </rd-widget-body>
      <rd-widget-footer>
        Footer

      </rd-widget-footer>
    </rd-widget>
  </div>
```

Now this is my PHP-code: very simple and straight forward: (PS: using slim)

```
// 4) Gets all TAGS related to this WORKSPACE
$app->get('/test5', function (Request $request, Response $response) {
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName("gtmdocx");
    $client->setAuthConfig('service_account.json');

    $client->setScopes(['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/tagmanager.readonly',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/tagmanager.manage.accounts',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/tagmanager.edit.containers',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/tagmanager.publish'
    ]);

    $service = new Google_Service_TagManager($client);
    $containers = $service->accounts_containers_workspaces_tags->listAccountsContainersWorkspacesTags('accounts/1746756959/containers/7454209/workspaces/8');
    echo $_GET['callback'] . '('.json_encode($containers).')';

});
```

If you look at the timing on response:
[image]

I hope someone has experienced this before. This is really bothering me that it is using so much time to render. When i type in directly the URL in browser i get response right away, but in angularjs as front its slow. Im using JSONP to fetch because of CORS, can this be the problem?

Comment: Is it possible to run this locally so you avoid the cors issue? Another problem I see is in your .then you give the function a name.. typically you pass an anonymous function there: function(response) {} <- no name

Comment: @floor thanks, i removed the function names on all http.requests. I installed xampp to test this localy and ill get back to you if this works faster or not.

Comment: Still very slow even in Localhost. Maby this is because of i am using JSONP or that google service is so slow... ill try some more to see what is causing this.

Comment: Is the data set you get back large? What might be the cause is you are binding a massive data set to a scope variable which takes time to process and render. You could try and implement a lazy loading or paging the data. For instance if you have 1000 account records but only want to display 50 at a time, only render and page the rest so that an event / action would load 50 more. If you are able to run it locally you don't need to use JSONP just make a get request.

Comment: @floor there is no massive data set, maximum 10-20 sets wich is displayed. I had multiple controllers on same page so i divided one controller per view and split the tables to its own view. Now i got a little faster response from 1.5s to 800ms on external resource call. This has improved alot now and ive added "spinner" so it looks a little better.